# SQL Query Failed to retrieve data from database. Subquery returned more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem: the query just stopped working. I have a message:

> Failed to retrieve data from the database. Subquery returned more than one value.

Here is the code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    k.animal_i d,
    a.animal_type,
    a.animal_name,
    a.breed_group,
    k.kennel_no,
    a.extra1,
    (SELECT
         m.memo_text
     FROM
         SYSADM.animal AS a
     INNER JOIN 
         SYSADM.memo AS m ON a.animal_id = m.memo_id
     WHERE
        m.memo_id = k.animal_id
        AND m.memo_type = 'GROOMING') AS memo,
    (SELECT
         tr.visit_type
     FROM
         SYSADM.animal AS a
     INNER JOIN 
         SYSADM.treatment AS tr ON tr.animal_id = a.animal_id
     WHERE
         a.animal_id = k.animal_id
         AND tr.visit_type IN ('SURGERY', 'RTO SPAYNEUTER',
                               'SNAPP SPAYNEUTER', 'SPAYNEUT SURG')
         AND dateDiff(d, tr.treatment_date, getdate()) < 10) AS visitType,
    (SELECT
         tr.treatment_date
     FROM
         SYSADM.animal AS a
     INNER JOIN 
         SYSADM.treatment AS tr ON tr.animal_id = a.animal_id
     WHERE
         a.animal_id = k.animal_id
         AND tr.visit_type IN ('SURGERY', 'RTO SPAYNEUTER',
                               'SNAPP SPAYNEUTER', 'SPAYNEUT SURG')
         AND dateDiff(d, tr.treatment_date, getdate() ) < 10) AS treatmentDate
FROM
    SYSADM.kennel AS k
INNER JOIN 
    SYSADM.animal AS a ON k.animal_id = a.animal_id
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    SYSADM.memo AS m ON k.animal_id = m.memo_id
INNER JOIN 
    SYSADM.treatment AS tr ON tr.animal_id = a.animal_id
WHERE
    k.outcome_date_null = 'Y'
    AND a.extra1 IN ('BATHE', 'BATHE ASAP', 'BRUSH', 'GROOM')
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                    FROM SYSADM.kennel
                    WHERE k.outcome_type IN ('RTO', 'TRANSFER')
                      AND NOT k.outcome_date_null = 'Y')
```

Comment: Try running your subqueries on their own against your actual database, using the parameters that cause this issue, and see which one(s) return more than one value.

Comment: And then you might have to add `MIN/MAX` to guarantee a single value.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I've added TOP 1, works like a charm!